# ¿Cómo guardar archivos que su nombre contenga espacios en ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola he estado desarrollando un formulario que guarde archivos en una carpeta en mi servidor, me funciona bien, lo he escrito en **ASP.NET c#** este es una pequeña parte del código:

```cs
  HttpPostedFile file = contextfile[0];
  MapPath = (space) ? pathWithSpace.ToUpper() : MapPath+file.FileName.ToUpper();
  file.SaveAs(MapPath);
```

***space*** variable que uso para saber si es tiene espacio o no,  ***pathWithSpace*** y ***MapPath*** son ambos variables *string* que guardan sea la ruta con espacio o sin espacio respectivamente.

Cuando viene con espacio se ve así la ruta:

> 'C:\USERS\ISMAEL\DESKTOP\PROYECTOS\FINALAPP\CONTRACTOS\AJUSTES MODULO 
>     FACTURACIÓN.DOCX'

Yo le agrege las comillas al principio y final, ya que cuando uno usa la terminal y se quiere acceder a una carpeta con espacios lo hacemos con las comillas como: `cd 'c:\USERS\ROJO VIVO'`

sin espacios de doc se ve asi:

> C:\USERS\ISMAEL\DESKTOP\PROYECTOS\FINALAPP\CONTRACTOS\AJUSTES_MODULO_ 
>     FACTURACIÓN.DOCX

pero no me funciona cuando lo hago de forma con espacios.

la versión de ASP.NET es la 4.0

Comment: Que versión de .NET y C# manejas, realmente nunca he usado aspx, pero en en las versiones que uso esta permitido poner un @ (arroba/at) al principio de una cadena para escapar todos los caracteres especiales.

Comment: La recomendación siempre es no usar espacios :/ Pero Windows, al menos, usa comillas dobles para indicar que la ruta es una cadena y escapa el espacio con backslash ```\```

Comment: @BrianJerezBaez utilizo la version 4.0, en otra parte del proyecto he usado ese @, entonces si lo soporta

Comment: @Alfabravo dale gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

No tiene sentido hacer la distinción entre si tiene espacios o no los tienes, con un único método cubres las dos posibilidades.

El problema que tienes es que envuelves el path del archivo con comillas simples, y deberías hacerlo con comillas dobles

```
string PathCorrecto = "\"" + path + "\"";
```

Comment: ok, ya lo cambio y comento como me fue, gracias :)

Comment: Ya he logrado  que el path sea uno solo sin distinción ahora el valor del path es asi:

"C:\Users\Ismael_Cabana\Desktop\LudyCommerce Proyectos\LudycommerceADM_QA\contractos\ERRORES 10DIC2019.DOCX"

pero me arroja un error: 
Caracteres no válidos en la ruta de acceso.

sera que el punto lo esta afectando?

Comment: OK, veo que lo resolviste con la @

Answer (score 1):

Puedes escapar los caracteres de la siguiente manera

```
var ubicacion = @"C:\Carpeta\Mi Archivo.xls";
```

y en caso de que te saque caracteres invalidos, puedes saber que caracteres son incorrectos de la siguiente manera y renombrar el archivo de manera respectiva.

```
var FilePath = string.Concat(FilePath.Split(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())).Trim();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en mi caso no tengo algo como 
var ubicacion = @"C:\Carpeta\Mi Archivo.xls";
mas bien recibo la ruta en una variable, osea que no tengo un string ".." sino que viene ya de otro lado en este caso del cliente

puedo hacer lo siguiente

var ubicacion = "@" + mivariablepath 

seria posible?

Comment: Relamente no se si puedas hacer lo siguiente var SegundaVariable = @"" + miVariable

Comment: La otra opción de la que tampoco estoy seguro sería haciendo uso de Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp y usando algun metodo que convierta a literal, creo que eso convierte automaticamente espacios a su representacion de escape.

Comment: Dale muchas gracias.